# How I can put this gradient in a XML resource?

Tags: android, xml, gradient

this is a simple question, but I don't know how to do it.

The gradient has two parts, the result is this.

[image: Gradient]

The code generated is the next, but I don't know how to put inside an only one XML to use as a background.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient 
android:type="linear"
android:centerX="30%" 
android:startColor="#00ffffff" 
android:centerColor="#FFffffff" 
android:endColor="#00ffffff" 
android:angle="0"/>
</shape>

-------------------------------------------------
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient 
android:type="radial"
android:centerX="50%" 
android:centerY="50%" 
android:startColor="#00ffffff" 
android:centerColor="#FFffffff" 
android:endColor="#00ffffff" 
android:gradientRadius="30"/>
</shape>
```

Thanks

**EDIT**:

CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:type="linear"
                android:centerX="30%"
                android:startColor="#00ffffff"
                android:centerColor="#FFffffff"
                android:endColor="#00ffffff"
                android:angle="0"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:type="radial"
                android:centerX="50%"
                android:centerY="50%"
                android:startColor="#00ffffff"
                android:centerColor="#FFffffff"
                android:endColor="#00ffffff"
                android:gradientRadius="30"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

RESULT

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient 
                android:type="linear"
                android:centerX="30%" 
                android:startColor="#00ffffff" 
                android:centerColor="#FFffffff" 
                android:endColor="#00ffffff" 
                android:angle="0"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient 
                android:type="radial"
                android:centerX="50%" 
                android:centerY="50%" 
                android:startColor="#00ffffff" 
                android:centerColor="#FFffffff" 
                android:endColor="#00ffffff" 
                android:gradientRadius="30"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

more about Layer List (and other) [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

Comment: Thanks, I've created the same, but the result is not the same as in the image. I'm going to post it in the first message.

Comment: and what is wrong with this result bitmap? because isn't symetric like first picture? you have `android:centerX="30%"` in first layer